# How to uninstall Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've decided to use JWT and completely remove Laravel Passport from the project.

I was trying to start with `composer remove laravel/passport`. However, it does no good:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Laravel\Passport\Passport' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Removal failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What could be the right and safe removing procedure?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can remove passport by manually deleting this line `"laravel/passport": "^4.0"` in your `composer.json` file then run `composer update`.

If you're running Laravel 5.4 or below, make sure to remove this line in your `app.config` file `Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class`

And all classes that relies on passport must be edited as well. The most common classes are:

1. `User` model, remove the `HasApiToken` trait.
2. `AuthServiceProvider`, remove `Passport::routes();` in your boot method.
3. Your `config/auth.php`, change your driver option for `api` authentication

Comment: `php artisan migrate:refresh` run at the end of step. To remove the Passport Migrations in database migrations table. but please be careful in you are in production.

Comment: Instead of deleting manually from composer.json I would prefer: composer remove laravel/passport

Answer (score 23):

With **Laravel 7**, I did it this way:

**Step 1.** In the file `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`, remove these two lines:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

```
Passport::routes();
```

**Step 2.**

```
$ composer remove laravel/passport
$ rm -r ./resources/js/components/passport # if any
$ rm -r ./resources/views/vendor/passport # if any
```

**Step 3.** In the file `resources/js/app.js`, remove passport components registration. You may also find and remove these registered components if you used it somewhere:

```
$ grep -rn 'passport-authorized-clients'     resources/js/*
$ grep -rn 'passport-personal-access-tokens' resources/js/*
$ grep -rn 'passport-clients'                resources/js/*
```

**Step 4.** Find and remove `HasApiTokens` from your models:

```
$ grep -rn HasApiTokens *
```

Remove also the import line going with it:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

**Step 5.** Remove `oauth` keys

```
$ rm storage/oauth-*.key
```

**Step 6.** In the file `config/auth.php`, look for `guards`:`api`:`driver` and revert from `passport` to `token`.

**Step 7.** Drop Passport tables and clean migration table

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> Schema::drop('oauth_access_tokens');
>>> Schema::drop('oauth_auth_codes');
>>> Schema::drop('oauth_clients');
>>> Schema::drop('oauth_personal_access_clients');
>>> Schema::drop('oauth_refresh_tokens');
>>> DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', 'like', '%_oauth_access_tokens_table')->delete();
>>> DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', 'like', '%_oauth_auth_codes_table')->delete();
>>> DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', 'like', '%_oauth_clients_table')->delete();
>>> DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', 'like', '%_oauth_personal_access_clients_table')->delete();
>>> DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', 'like', '%_oauth_refresh_tokens_table')->delete();
>>> exit
```

**Step 8.** And finally, refresh your installation:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php artisan optimize:clear
$ npm run dev
```

Comment: Probably best to create a migration to drop the tables in the case that other developers are working on the same codebase or this is already on staging/production.

Answer (score 9):

After following Paul's steps. Remove the Passport Migrations in database migrations table and run command `artisan migrate:refresh`.

Comment: Add this as a comment under Paul's answer