# Laravel Passport custom user provider: provider option does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-7

I'm trying to set a custom user provider with **Laravel Passport** as explained in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#customizing-the-user-provider):

**Customizing The User Provider**

> If your application uses more than one
>   authentication user provider, you may specify which user provider the
>   password grant client uses by providing a --provider option when
>   creating the client via the artisan passport:client --password
>   command. The given provider name should match a valid provider defined
>   in your config/auth.php configuration file. You can then protect your
>   route using middleware to ensure that only users from the guard's
>   specified provider are authorized.

But when I run:

```
php artisan passport:client --password --provider foo_users
```

I get the following error message:

> The "--provider" option does not exist.

Am I using it wrong or is it a bug in **Laravel Passport** ?

Comment: What version of Passport do you have installed? The `--provider` option appears new to 9.x. It doesn't exist on 8.x or below.

Comment: Laravel Framework 7.10.2 shipped with  "laravel/passport": "^8.4" by default. How should I upgrade "laravel/passport" ?

Comment: Change the composer version, then follow the guide to update your application: https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/master/UPGRADE.md

Comment: Instead of upgrading, I removed Laravel Passport following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62021326/931247) and made a fresh install. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot.